# script mysql para comprobar indice

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysqldb

Tengo las bases : base1, base2, base3 , con la tabla Libros. Necesito alterar uno de los campos, en este caso "codigo" para que sea del tipo "UNIQUE".
Quisiera armar un script único, que revise si el índice ya existe ( se crea por default con el nombre del campo).
Si el indice existe, que no haga nada.
Si no existe, ejecute ALTER TABLE libros ADD UNIQUE (codigo);

Investigando encontré el siguiente código :

```html
SELECT COUNT(1) IndexIsThere 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS 
WHERE table_schema='base1'  
AND table_name='Libros' 
AND index_name='codigo';
```

Esto me devuelve un 0 si el indice no existe y 1 si existe.
Como puedo lograr lo que necesito ? Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida !

Comment: ¿Qué versión de MySQL está usando?

Comment: Es un desarrollo algo antiguo , la version de MySql es la 5.7.35

Comment: Una opción sería usar un procedimiento almacenado y una sentencia preparada. El procedimiento almacenado puede recibir un JSON (dado que usa 5.7.x) con una estructura que indique el esquema, la columna, el índice, el nombre del nuevo índice (si así lo desea) y cualquier otra información (es flexible) e iterar sobre ese JSON con todos los índices que desee crear (evaluando si existen con la consulta mostrada en la pregunta).

Comment: en realidad es 1 solo indice llamado 'codigo' , el problema es que si existe crea uno nuevo ,,

Comment: Sí, pero sobre tres esquemas (base1, base2 y base3) según entiendo de la pregunta.

Comment: Es el mismo esquema, varia el nombre de la database

Comment: Perfecto, entonces su parámetro de entrada puede ser algo como: `{"table_schema": ["base1", "base2", "base3"], "table_name": "Libros", "index_name": "codigo"}`.